# How to properly use the UnProject method in OpenTK and get world coordinates from mouse hover?

Tags: vb.net, opentk

I am trying to get world coordinates by hovering my mouse over the `GLControl` control where the world is being rendered in. I've found dozens of examples and solutions but I can't work with them, I am still learning and haven't got to their point. But I kept digging and found some examples and picked one that is approved by its original author which works with a similar render construction but still doesn't seem to work for me.

I've set up a window to output the converted coordinates. I am getting `x, y = 0` at the center of the control, which means that I'm possibly going the right way. When I move the mouse around the `x` and `y` axis it outputs proper values (eg. the higher the mouse from the center of the control, the higher `y` is, etc.), but only to like `-1.65/1.65` max from the center. It does not seem like it gets my `Modelview` matrix, because It should differ depending on the `eyeZ`, which it doesn't. Changing the `eyeZ` has no effect at all. It still acts as if I didn't "zoom in/out".

I've set up my `Projection`, `Modelview` matrices and `Viewport` like this:

```
    GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Projection)
    GL.LoadIdentity()

    GL.LoadMatrix(Matrix4.CreatePerspectiveFieldOfView(Math.PI / 4, glControl.Width / glControl.Height, 1.0F, 128.0F))

    GL.MatrixMode(MatrixMode.Modelview)
    GL.LoadIdentity()

    GL.LoadMatrix(Matrix4.LookAt(0F, 0F, zoom, 0F, 0F, 0F, 0F, 1.0F, 0F))

    GL.Viewport(0, 0, glControl.Width, glControl.Height)
```

Then I have these two functions that get called when my mouse moves over the `GLControl` and pass in the mouse's coordinates.

```
Public Function screenToWorld(ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer) As Vector4
    Dim modelViewMatrix As Matrix4
    Dim projectionMatrix As Matrix4
    Dim viewport(4) As Integer

    GL.GetFloat(GetPName.ModelviewMatrix, modelViewMatrix)
    GL.GetFloat(GetPName.ProjectionMatrix, projectionMatrix)
    GL.GetInteger(GetPName.Viewport, viewport)

    Return UnProject(projectionMatrix, modelViewMatrix, New Size(viewport(2), viewport(3)), New Vector2(x, y))
End Function

Public Function UnProject(ByRef projection As Matrix4, ByVal view As Matrix4, ByVal viewport As Size, ByVal mouse As Vector2) As Vector4
    Dim vec As Vector4

    vec.X = 2.0F * mouse.X / viewport.Width - 1
    vec.Y = -(2.0F * mouse.Y / viewport.Height - 1)
    vec.Z = 0F
    vec.W = 1.0F

    Dim viewInv As Matrix4 = Matrix4.Invert(view)
    Dim projInv As Matrix4 = Matrix4.Invert(projection)

    Vector4.Transform(vec, projInv, vec)
    Vector4.Transform(vec, viewInv, vec)

    If vec.W > Single.Epsilon OrElse vec.W < Single.Epsilon Then
        vec.X /= vec.W
        vec.Y /= vec.W
        vec.Z /= vec.W
    End If

    Return vec
End Function
```

Also I refrain from using orthrographic projection.